# Ubuntu Intermittently Refuses New Network Connections

Tags: networking, server

I have an desktop running Ubuntu 22.10 that allows SSH connections and has a Plex server running on it. It generally runs fine except that it will occasionally refuse connections - SSH fails with Connection refused and so does a new Plex window. The network isn't down; any existing video stream doesn't stop and an open SSH shell will continue to work, I just can't add a new connection.

Are there settings I should be changing to increase inbound connections or ensure ports remain free?

Edit:  journalctl doesn't return anything that looks like a smoking gun to me. This connection error occured multiple times yesterday, and this is the entire days logs from NetworkManager  :

```
Mar 29 00:00:43  NetworkManager[864]: <info>  [1680062443.3505] dhcp4 (enp1s0): state changed new lease, address=192.168.1.52
Mar 29 00:56:58  NetworkManager[864]: <info>  [1680065818.2973] dhcp4 (enp1s0): state changed new lease, address=192.168.1.52
Mar 29 01:51:41  NetworkManager[864]: <info>  [1680069101.3066] dhcp4 (enp1s0): state changed new lease, address=192.168.1.52
Mar 29 02:47:40  NetworkManager[864]: <info>  [1680072460.2969] dhcp4 (enp1s0): state changed new lease, address=192.168.1.52
Mar 29 03:41:31  NetworkManager[864]: <info>  [1680075691.3097] dhcp4 (enp1s0): state changed new lease, address=192.168.1.52
Mar 29 04:36:15  NetworkManager[864]: <info>  [1680078975.3003] dhcp4 (enp1s0): state changed new lease, address=192.168.1.52
Mar 29 04:53:46  NetworkManager[864]: <info>  [1680080026.3071] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
Mar 29 04:53:46  NetworkManager[864]: <info>  [1680080026.4636] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Mar 29 05:31:29  NetworkManager[864]: <info>  [1680082289.2930] dhcp4 (enp1s0): state changed new lease, address=192.168.1.52
Mar 29 06:24:14  NetworkManager[864]: <info>  [1680085454.3034] dhcp4 (enp1s0): state changed new lease, address=192.168.1.52
Mar 29 07:19:56  NetworkManager[864]: <info>  [1680088796.3271] dhcp4 (enp1s0): state changed new lease, address=192.168.1.52
Mar 29 08:04:06  NetworkManager[864]: <info>  [1680091446.3069] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
Mar 29 08:04:07  NetworkManager[864]: <info>  [1680091447.5300] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Mar 29 08:14:57  NetworkManager[864]: <info>  [1680092097.3178] dhcp4 (enp1s0): state changed new lease, address=192.168.1.52
Mar 29 08:39:27  NetworkManager[864]: <info>  [1680093567.3073] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
Mar 29 08:39:27  NetworkManager[864]: <info>  [1680093567.5565] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
```

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting

Comment: Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: I have the same problem. I'm running plex in an LXC container and the host goes back and forth between reachable and unreachable. If I'm already connected via ssh it doesn't get disconnected. However, if I ping 1.1.1.1 from the plex server, I can see periods of about 4 minutes where pings stop responding. and the icmp_seq has clearly jumped.


`Jul 08 00:04:09 64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=2887 ttl=57 time=3.24 ms`    
`Jul 08 00:08:11 64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=3123 ttl=57 time=3.72 ms`